# seek in compressed file

Tags: c, compression, seek

I have text files weighing ≈ 200GB.
I'm storing in DB pairs of `key` - `position_in_file`,
and reaching the data using `fseek`.

Is there recommended way to compress the files,
and seek to position in a compressed file,
without decompressing from the beginning of the file.

[I prefer to use C as language]
[No need to perform writes. No need to be super fast]

Comment: Probably not. And if yes, it would not take much less time than uncompressing the file and access the content there. Reason: To find a position in a compressed file you practically have to uncompress it without generating the output until you reach the desired position.

Comment: Instead of compressing the whole file, compress the separate data chunks separately, then you can still use the position in the file and seeks as you do now.

Comment: The data blocks are about 1KB-1MB each. Are you suggesting to `gzip` each one of them separately ?

Comment: @nv3: when you have gigabytes of compressed data, seeking into the compressed data and doing a partial uncompress (if your compression format supports it) can take a *lot* less time.  Two formats that support seeking and partial uncompressing are `bzip2`, and concantenated `gzip` chunks.

Comment: Yes that's my suggestion, but not by calling any external `gzip` binary of course, use e.g. `zlib`. Sure there is a trade-off with longer latencies when a specific data block needs to be uncompressed, but if you have some sort of caching of uncompressed data much of that can be overcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [example of random access of deflated data](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c).  It runs through the compressed data once to build a random access index with entry points at about every 1 MB of uncompressed data.  (You can change that density.)  Each entry point is at a deflate block boundary, and saves the 32K of uncompressed data that precedes it in order to populate the sliding dictionary for decompression.

Comment: FWIW: I've develop a command line tool upon zlib's zran.c which creates indexes for gzip files: https://github.com/circulosmeos/gztool
**It can even create an index for a still-growing gzip file** (for example a log created by rsyslog directly in gzip format) thus reducing in the practice to zero the time of index creation. See the -S (Supervise) option.

Answer (score 2):

I know of two ways to do this.

The standard `gunzip` program is able to successfully decompress the concatenation of two or more `.gz` files.  So you can compress the file in chunks, and build an index which tells you where to seek into the "chunked" gzip file to begin uncompressing.

For example, if I had the (artificially tiny) database

```
a    apple
b    beneficial
c    carotene
d    diatomaceous
```

and if I weren't compressing, I could build a table of keys and seek offsets that would look like this:

```
a    0
b    8
c    21
d    32
```

If I wanted to make a chunk-compressed file, using chunks of size two lines, I could do that like this (in shell, not C):

```
sed -n 1,2p d | gzip > d.gz
sed -n 3,4p d | gzip >> d.gz
```

My index for the chunk-compressed file would have three fields: a key, a seek offset into the chunk-compressed file, and an additional offset (after uncompressing) to find that key within the chunk:

```
a    0    0
b    0    8
c    41   0
c    41   11
```

The `bzip2` program has some facilities for this built in, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: Addendum: What's built in to `bzip2`, I later determined, is a certain level of support for distinct "chunks" in the file.  There's nothing built-in to explicitly index those chunks.  (I now have my own patches to `bzip2` to construct and make use of an index.)